# Can JConsole be used to monitor time required to execute particular methods for a web application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, performance-testing, jconsole

After I connect to weblogic process through JConsole, I see some overall statistics but not the method-wise breakup of performance (time required for each method/class). Besides, as of now, I don't see how particular methods may be profiled using JConsole. Am I looking at the right tool? Or should I go for JProfiler instead?

Comment: I don't think JConsole has what you need. Weblogic does provide some internal performance monitoring tools. Check out: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/cico-wldf-091073.html

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong tool.

JConsole is a montiring tool. It will help you look at metrics like classes loaded, Heap Space, Perm Space, Threads Live, Collections etc etc...

What you want to do is profiling, not monitoring, try jvisualvm you can find it under JAVA_HOME/bin right next to JConsole.

BE aware that these tools have limited capability, I believe jvisualvm will make it to profile an application up to 65k classes, if you want to go bigger you should try JProfiler, Netbeans Profiler, or Yourkit maybe even Solaris Studio. It all depends on your platform and taste.